# Document design feedback

Tags: typography

In the following weeks I am going to need to make several documents like this [one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3FvzClUOz2ddlJBQklhd0JwX2c/view?usp=sharing). Which are going to be handouts given to students covering the main topics of the lesson.

At the moment I am dividing the document using either `parbox` (for single lines) or `minipage` (for multiple lines) combined with the `tabular` environment for better alignment. I am also using `parkskip` to define the vertical space between each box:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=0.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\definecolor{red}{RGB}{153,0,0}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{51,102,153}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}

\begin{document}

\parbox[t]{200mm}{\huge{\textbf{Resumo Aula 1 - Curso MATLAB}}}

\parbox[t]{200mm}{\huge{$\bullet$ Concatenação e criação de matrizes - Operador \texttt{[]} e \texttt{:}}}

%\fbox
{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{140mm}
    \Large
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
    \begin{tabular}{ l l l }
        \texttt{a = [1,2,3,4]} & \texttt{a = [1 2 3 4]} & Vetor Coluna \\
        \texttt{a = [1,2,3,4]} &  & Vetor Linha  \\
        \texttt{c = [a,a]} & \texttt{c = [a a]} & Concatenização Vertical \\
        \texttt{C = [a;a]} & & Concatenização Horizontal
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
}
%\fbox
{
    \begin{minipage}[c]{100mm}
    \Large
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1} 
    \begin{tabular}{ l l }
        \texttt{zeros} & Matriz de zeros \\
        \texttt{ones} & Matriz de números 1 \\
        \texttt{eye} & Matriz identidade  \\
        \texttt{rand} & Matriz de números aleatórios \\
        \texttt{zeros(3,3)} &  Matriz 3x3\\
        \texttt{zeros(1,3)} &  Matriz 3x1
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
}

\parbox[b]{65mm}{\Large{\texttt{inicio:incremento:fim}}}
\parbox[b]{60mm}{\Large{\texttt{1:2:10}}$\rightarrow$ \texttt{[1 3 5 7 9]}}
\parbox[b]{40mm}{\Large{\texttt{1:4}}$\rightarrow$ \texttt{[1 2 3 4]}}
\parbox[c]{40mm}{Se o incremento não for especificado é considerado um incremento de 1}

\parbox[t]{200mm}{\huge{$\bullet$ Indexação - Operadores \texttt{()} e \texttt{:}}}

%\fbox
{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{200mm}
    \Large
     \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
    \begin{tabular}{ l l }
        \texttt{A(indice)} & Procura através das colunas \\
        \texttt{A(indiceLinha, indiceColuna)} & Intersecção do vetor \texttt{indiceLinha} e \texttt{indiceColuna}  \\
        \texttt{end} & Seleciona o último elemento de uma dimensão \\
        \texttt{:} & Seleciona toda uma dimensão
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
}

%\fbox
{
    \begin{minipage}[c]{130mm}
        \Large
        \includegraphics{exemploIndexacao}
        
        \texttt{\textcolor{red}{indiceLinha} = [1 3]}
        
        \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{indiceColuna} = [2 3]}
        
        \texttt{A(\textcolor{red}{indiceLinha}, \textcolor{blue}{indiceColuna})}
        
    \end{minipage}
}
%\fbox
{
    \begin{minipage}[c]{135mm}
         \Large
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
        
        \begin{tabular}{ l l }
            \texttt{A(:,2)} & Segunda coluna completa  \\
            \texttt{A(:)} & Todos os elementos de A em um vetor coluna   \\
            \texttt{A([1 3],:)} & Primeira e terceira linha completa \\
            \texttt{A(1,end)} & Primeira e última coluna
        \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
}

\scriptsize\raggedleft\vfill{\textbf{Copyright \copyright\ 2016 Pedro Dreyer (pedrodreyer@hotmail.com)}}

\end{document}
```

What do you guys think? Is there a more correct/elegant way to archive the same result?

some other questions:

1- Can I make the `parbox` width be exactly the size of the text inside it?

2-Why I am receiving an `overfull \hbox` warning? The width of the `minipages` are more than enough to fit its contents.

3- Any input/comment on the overall design of the document?

Comment: Why not use `beamer` class? 1- You can use `calc`'s package `\widthof{text}` command as Input for the `parbox`. 2- No idea since I don't know which boxes are giving the warning. 3- Is it a presentation?

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Not a presentation. I am giving some MATLAB lessons and this is supposed to be a handout covering the main topics of the lesson.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, you will have to make a few of these documents, so here are some suggestions:

1. Avoid landscape orientations. It creates hard to follow text.
2. Let LaTeX guide you as to the rhythm and typography of the page. Use `\section*, \subsection*` etc. to define heading levels.
3. Write macros for tables you use often and move the styling element to the tabular specification. Add the matrix package for this.
4. Work to have a mimimum amount of  mark-up in the document.
5. Don't try to fit six rows in the space of the four (first tables). Vertical alignment is not easy.
6. Embrace `UTF-8` and LuaLaTeX.

Here a MWE for the first part of the document.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{arial}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0.8cm,right=0cm,top=1cm,bottom=0.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{153,0,0}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{51,102,153}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}

\newenvironment{matlab}{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{>{\bfseries\ttfamily} l >{\ttfamily} l  >{\itshape}l }%
}{\end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\matcmd}[2]{
\bgroup\ttfamily
#1$\rightarrow$ #2\egroup
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Resumo Aula 1 - Curso MATLAB}

\subsection*{Concatenação e criação de matrizes - Operador \texttt{[]} e \texttt{:}}

\begin{matlab}
        zeros & Matriz de zeros &\\
        ones & Matriz de números 1 & \\
        eye & Matriz identidade & \\
        rand & Matriz de números aleatórios & \\
        zeros(3,3) &  Matriz 3x3 &\\
        zeros(1,3) &  Matriz 3x1 &
\end{matlab}
\begin{matlab}
       a = [1,2,3,4] & a = [1 2 3 4] & Vetor Coluna \\
       a = [1,2,3,4] &  & Vetor Linha  \\
       c = [a,a] & c = [a a] & Concatenização Vertical \\
       C = [a;a] & & Concatenização Horizontal
\end{matlab}

\matcmd{inicio:incremento:fim}{}

\matcmd{1:2:10}{[1 3 5 7 9]}

Se o incremento não for especificado é considerado um incremento de 1

\matcmd{1:4}{[1 2 3 4]}

\subsection*{Indexação - Operadores \texttt{()} e \texttt{:}}

\begin{matlab}
 A(indice) & Procura através das colunas &\\
 A(indiceLinha, indiceColuna) & Intersecção do vetor \texttt{indiceLinha} e \texttt{indiceColuna} & \\
end& Seleciona o último elemento de uma dimensão &\\
       : & Seleciona toda uma dimensão
\end{matlab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Yannis, [that looks nice](https://www.overleaf.com/read/dshjcnrttkpy)! I would also recommend the use of footer to put the OP copyright text. And why Arial? Latin Modern is so beautiful. There's also, `tikz` for making figures, or `easybmat`for making matrices. Could also, following the OP's logic, use `titlesec` to make the subsections with a bullet mark before the title.

Comment: @Yannis, Thanks for the thoughtful answer, the MWE looks very nice. I am going to study it carefully to try to wrap my head around some of your proposed suggestions.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Normally I use Arial for MWE and tests, uses less typing:) In general I don't like bullets, but your idea is good, if one wants it.

Comment: @PedroDreyer Thanks. If you need any additional info just add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also going to suggest a few packages that came to mind, maybe they can be of some help for future documents.

- [`minted`](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) package, for code hightlighting. For short code snippets may be irrelevant but for code blocks is definetly a good tool. It is powered with Pygments which support over 300 languages and has several styles available out of the box. Be awere that this package Needs to compile with `-shell-escape` and maybe it also needs to have python installed (of this I'm not 100% sure).
- [`titlesec`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) to format the sections and subsections according to your needs.
- [`tikz` and `pgf`](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) to make awesome font consistent drawings.
- [`fancyhdr`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) to format the footers and headers. In your case, maybe it would be nice to use the footer for the copyright text and the header for some fancy logo.